# Either java.lang.ClassNotFoundException or Could not find or load main class error

Tags: java, windows, jdbc

First time trying to run some Java code under Windows here, and I got:

```
D:\Tmp>java JDBC_SQLServer
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at JDBC_SQLServer.main(JDBC_SQLServer.java:19)
```

I.e., java finds main but didn't find the lib. Now, --

```
D:\Tmp>java -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\lib" JDBC_SQLServer
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
Error: Could not find or load main class JDBC_SQLServer
```

I.e., java finds the sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver lib but can't find main now.

The JDBC_SQLServer is just a hack from 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connection-url-sample

How to solve it? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classpath needs to contain the current directory (in order to find your class and its `main`-method and the jar-file (not only a directory with jars in it), so a call could look like this:

```
D:\Tmp>java -cp "C:/mssql/lib/sqljdbc41.jar;." JDBC_SQLServer
```

You don't need to use backslashes for the paths and because backslashes are often parsed specially by the shell you use, I personally try to avoid them as much as possible.